# Magic Fields - Duplicate group outputting always the same first image

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, duplicates

teSo I'm trying to output a text and an image field from a duplicate group through Magic Fields, the text field shows the different duplicates but the image field keeps displaying the url to the first image repeatedly. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
<?php
$articlephotos="&amp;w=728&amp;h=560&amp;q=95&amp;zc=1&amp;iar=0&amp;far=0";
?>

<?php $myContents = get_group('contents'); // use the Custom Group name
  foreach($myContents as $contents){ ?>

<?php  if( get('contents_text', true) ) { ?>
<div class="contents"><?php echo $contents['contents_text'][1]; ?></div>
<?php } ?>

<?php  if( get('contents_image', true) ) { ?>
<div class="post_container" style="padding-bottom: 24px;">
<div class="photo_outside">
<div class="photo_inside">
<img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/phpThumb/phpThumb.php?src=<?php echo get_image('contents_image',$contents,$contents,0); ?><?php echo $articlephotos ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($ID) ?>" alt="<?php echo get_the_title($ID) ?>">
</div><!-- end photos_inside -->
</div><!-- end photos_outside -->
</div>
<?php } ?>

<?php } ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Var Dump outputs:

> array(2) { [1]=> array(2) { ["contents_text"]=> array(1) { [1]=>
>   string(1085) "
>
> Text 01
>
> " } ["contents_image"]=> array(1) { [1]=> array(2) { ["original"]=>
>   string(122) "http://www.mysite.com/image01.jpg" ["thumb"]=>
>   string(122) "http://www.mysite.com/image01.jpg" } } } [2]=> array(2) {
>   ["contents_text"]=> array(1) { [1]=> string(1380) "
>
> Text 02
>
> " } ["contents_image"]=> array(1) { [1]=> array(2) { ["original"]=>
>   string(119) "http://www.mysite.com/image01.jpg" ["thumb"]=>
>   string(119) "http://www.mysite.com/image01.jpg" } } } }

I abbreviated the content of the texts and the image urls.

Comment: Can you `var_dump($myContents)` for us to see? I think it's probably because you need to use `0` for the first in an array, though really need to see what output you have to be honest first.

Comment: I edited my initial post and pasted the output there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution from the plug-in's group, thanks for your help!

```
<?php $elements = get_group('contents');
foreach($elements as $key => $element){                                      

if( get('contents_text', true) ) {
    echo '<div class="contents">';
    echo $element['contents_text'][1];
    echo '</div>'; 
}

$images = get_order_field('contents_text',$key);
foreach($images as $image){

if( get('contents_image', $key ,$image = true) ) {
    echo '<div class="photo_outside"><div class="photo_inside">';
    echo '<img src="' . get('contents_image', $key ,$image) .'">';
    echo '</div></div>';
    }

} } ?>
```